# JxBrowser Compatibility with RHEL 6

Tags: jxbrowser

We have a restriction on our linux version but want to still use JXBrowser. Is there a earlier version we can use which runs on RHEL 6.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have never tested [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) on RHEL 6.8, so there's no guaranty that it will work in this environment. Previous JxBrowser versions you can download from [Release Notes](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/forums/9000110576)

Comment: Hey Vladimir! Thanks for the help. We decided to give it a go with the latest version and ran into the following: IPCException IPC process exited with exit code 1. Any insights on what this means?

Comment: I need to take a look at all console output to let you know what might causes this error. Could you please enable JxBrowser logging, reproduce the issue and send me all console output: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013125-logging

Comment: Thanks for the update, that really helped. 
/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.0/jxbrowser-chromium: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by //tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.0/libjxbrowser-chromium-lib.so)
10:11:35 INFO: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.0/jxbrowser-chromium: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found. Looks like RHEL 6.8 will allow us to get 3.4.13. Is there a version of JxBrowser which has a Chromium which uses GLIBCXX_3.4.13?

Comment: As far as I remember even in JxBrowser 4.0 version Chromium engine was built with GLIBCXX_3.4.15. I'm sorry, but I cannot suggest an old version that is compatible with RHEL 6.8.

Comment: Completely understand! Thank you for all your assistance, much appreciated. You all are doing a great job over there.